# Vue.js Reactivity is not working properly in a prop

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I am using composition API in my Vue.js project. Suppose, I have a **ManageFeedback.vue** parent component and inside this I am using a child component namely **FeedbackModal**. Now I am also using a **feedback.js** composable file, importing every function, reactive values necessary from there. The child component FeedbackModal accepts a prop say feedbackData, which is I am importing from **feedback.js**. When user clicks to a button I am triggering a function in **feedback.js** to populate **feedbackData**.

That is fine I am getting my desired output. The problem is, when I am in child component, in **onMount** I am checking for scroll event, if scroll happens I use the fetch function in feedback.js to fetch the next page data, and inside the function it pushes the result to the feedbackData array, which I am using as a prop. But I don't get the data in the UI after scrolling, but the feedbackData changes I have checked.

So the problem is: changes in feedbackData is not reflecting in the child, although it is updating in feedback.js.

The feedbackData is declared like this in feedback.js:

```
const feedbackData = reactive([]);
```

Sample Parent component code:

```
<template>

<FeedbackModal  :feedback-data="feedbackData" />

</template>

<script setup>

import { useManageFeedback } from './js/feedback';


const {
    feedbackData,
    openFeedbackModal,
} = useManageFeedback();


</script>
```

Sample Child code:

```
<template>
 // using v-for to iterate and display feedback replies.
</template>


<script setup>
import { getReplies } from './js/feedback';

const props = defineProps(['feedbackData']);

const {
    getReplies,
} = useManageFeedback();

onMount(() => {
 // check for scroll event
 // getReplies();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Here, in Vue.js, when a hook is invoked, a new instance would be created. So, you are using different instances in the parent and the child components. They are totally different instances. You need to pass data using props and emit updating events from children. The `getReplies` need to be called via the parent, but the trigger event could be emitted from the child.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have resolved the problem by emitting from the child component.